# Running wasm module with wasmer cli

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-wasm

I am starting out with web-assembly following this guide: https://depth-first.com/articles/2020/06/29/compiling-rust-to-webassembly-a-simple-example/

When I compile the source with `cargo build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown --release` i get a `.wasm` file. Instead of importing this module in JavaScript, I want to uses [wasmer](https://docs.wasmer.io/ecosystem/wasmer/getting-started). I have installed wasmer 2.2.1, but when I try to run `wasmer run target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/hello.wasm`, I get the following error:

```
error: failed to run `target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/hello.wasm`
╰─▶ 1: No export `_start` found in the module.
       Similar functions found: `add_one`.
       Try with: wasmer target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/hello.wasm -i add_one
```

Is this the intended use of `wasmer`? If so, where should I search for culprits?

**EDIT**

I did not read the error message properly, it seems as if `wasmer run target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/hello.wasm -i add_one 1` does work and will return 2.

Comment: I imagine to make it work with `wasmer run hello.wasm` your crate should be a binary instead of a library

Comment: @kmdreko You're right, just learning how it works. I want to eventually be able to read data from a network socket, so I think the  `cargo build --target wasm32-wasi` is better suited for this. However, there is also `cargo wasi` and `wasm-bindgen` as seen in the sections *Writing Libraries* and *WebAssembly Interface Types* for the rust wasmtime docs: https://docs.wasmtime.dev/wasm-rust.html#writing-libraries. I believe the `wasm-bindgen` is only used for targeting web stuff with JavaScript interoperability, but why would one use `cargo wasi build` over `cargo build --target wasm32-wasi` ?